# How to fetch group-id of a processor in apache nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

Another question on Apache Nifi, how can i fetch the group id of a processor which also appears when you right click the processor and then click on stats? Is there a way to store this group id value as part of some attribute/flow file content.

I need the group id so that i can consume the bulletin messages from the rest api, to fetch the bulletin errors.

http[s]://{host}:{port}/nifi-api/controller/process-groups/{process-group-id}/status?recursive=true

Answer (score 1):

Swati, let's see. You are trying to read bulletins raised via API, correct? Try the Proces Groups -> Status with a recursive option, it has bulletins raised among other things, and it looks like those have the info you're after.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Here's a tip. In Chrome, open the View -> Developer Tools and switch to the Network -> XHR tab. This will list every API invocation the UI is performing and you can replicate the same, e.g.
http://localhost:8080/nifi-api/controller/process-groups/root/status?recursive=true

Comment: I am not really sure if this answers my question. I want to pass on this URL in PutEmail so that if there is any error/failure, a mail will be triggered which will be having fully formed URL so that the receiver can later check on the messages.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a sound approach. What if your NiFi instance is secured? And why would an email reader understand NiFi data structures? Maybe reconsider the design. I would fetch the info and parse the output, then send an email with meaningful description.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Processor ID, You can get the Process group ID to which it belongs through the below API

[http://{host}:{post}/nifi-api//processors/{id}](http://%7Bhost%7D:%7Bpost%7D/nifi-api//processors/%7Bid%7D)